# Django/Apache authentication successful but does not return @loginrequired view instead redirects to index

Tags: django, vue.js, apache, django-authentication

I have a Django/Vue application with token-based auth. I served this app on AWS before without problem. Now I want to serve it via Apache2 but it fails to open a 'login required' page after successful login. Here is my code:

views.py

```
def index(request):
    print('Access to page "home"')
    return render(request, 'index.html')


@login_required(login_url='/')
def memory(request):
    print('Access to page "memory"')
    return render(request, 'memory.html')
```

user_api.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@csrf_exempt
def doLogin(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    user = json.loads(body_unicode)
    dbUser = User.objects.filter(username=user['username'])
    if not dbUser:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    authenticatedUser = authenticate(username=user['username'], password=user['password'])

    if authenticatedUser:
        login(request, authenticatedUser)
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=authenticatedUser)

        return Response({'token': token.key},
                        status=HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=401)
```

LoginModal.vue

```
login() {
                if (!this.user.username || this.user.username == '' ||
                    !this.user.password || this.user.password == '') {
                    this.warningText = 'All fields must be filled.'
                    return
                }

                axios.post(this.backendAddress + 'api/user/login', this.user)
                    .then((response) => {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
                        document.cookie = 'apitoken=' + response.data.token
                        window.location.href = 'memory'
                    }, function (err) {
                        printError(err)
                    })
            }
```

After I entered my username/password and hit login, it makes the request and redirects to index with `?next=memory`, meaning that it doesn't recognized user as logged in. After successfull login I store my token as 'apitoken' parameter in the cookie. What's wrong with my method?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72594832/997832 @Richard